# Can't change Ruby Version using RVM

Tags: ruby

I'm running Lion DP4 with Ruby 1.8.7 preinstalled. For my new project I need the latest Ruby version though. Therefore installed rvm and the latest Ruby. Somehow when I try to use the new version it doesn't give me any errors, but the change just doesn't take effect.

```
~martin$ rvm use ruby 1.9.2 --default
Using /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
~martin$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

My .bash_profile file looks like this:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin" 
export PATH="/opt/local/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/texbin:${PATH}"
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/martin/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin 
source ~/.git-completion.bash
alias mysql '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql'
alias mysqladmin '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin'
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Can anyone tell me why me wanting to change the Ruby version is not working? Appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Martin

EDIT (2011/06/28 - 1:08PM):

Ok, for some really odd reason everything works now.
I guess my .bash_profile file somehow was messed up. In the beginning I thought that I installed it as root therefore changed the rvm path to

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

But I guess my path declaration in general was totally messed up. Now my .bash_profile file looks like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin 
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/sbin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/martin/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin 
source ~/.git-completion.bash
alias mysql '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql'
alias mysqladmin '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin'
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

@Mark 
Yes, I installed Ruby using MacPorts and hope that now I've fixed the path.

Comment: How are you installing Ruby - (the /opt you are attempting but partially failing to put in the path suggests use of Macports) - echo $PATH would also help us

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is not a real solution but a hack:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/_ruby
```

Note that this is not ideal since it might break scripts that start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

blablabla
```

Looking forward for a better answer in the meantime :)